# ¿Cómo configurar un archivo adjunto al enviar correo en Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

En la configuración del Job tengo:

[image: Parte 1 configuracion del job]

Añadí un trigger, una vez finalizada manda un correo y debería mandar un archivo adjunto:

[image: Parte 2 trigger de correo con archivo adjunto]

No logro enviar el archivo adjunto (Pdf, txt,.zip)

¿El adjunto iría en el campo "Attachments"?

Comment: no pude añadir etiquetas

Comment: Me parece que en el input Attachments debe ir la ruta absoluta del archivo que necesitas que se adjunte. Según veo, esa ruta es relativa y puede que no exista.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza he probado y me da el siguiente error "ERROR: Error accessing files to attach: Expecting Ant GLOB pattern, but saw 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\Avisare 2\workspace\hola.pdf'. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html for syntax"

Comment: Si tu archivo hola.pdf ya se encuentra en el workspace de Jenkins, croe que entonces deberías colocar hola.pdf solamente. Inténtalo nuevamente.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Excelente, dentro del Job tuve que crear la carpeta llamada "Workspace", alli inclui los archivos que queria enviar y al colocar solo hola.pdf lo envio correctamente, tendrias idea de como hacer para enviar un .hmlt + 10 imagenes .png, Gracias por tu valioso tiempo.

Comment: No he trabajado tanto con ese plugin de jenkins. No sé si eso será posible =\

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Agradecido por tu ayuda, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

El problema que comentas es algo que me preguntaba un compañero, simplemente es lo que se comenta, **agrega la ruta completa de tu workspace**:

```
'workspace/hola.zip'
```

y claro, asegura que exista.

Comment: He probado y no funciona añadiendo la ruta absoluta, debes añadir la ruta desde tu workspace de Jenkins (Job) y ahi si lo toma, saludos y gracias por la informacion

Comment: entonces agregaste el archivo dentro del workspace, y cual path configuraste? si estas en el workspace fue workspace/hola.zip como en tu imagen?

Comment: no, añadi dentro del job un directorio llamado workspace y lo que hice en Attanchment es añadir unicamente el nombre del archivo a adjuntar, "hola.pdf" y funciono. saludos.